How to draw a line chart date versus letter grade?
I have an evaluation process that produces letter grades based on performance (A is best and E is worst). I periodically evaluate the process and produce the outcome as a letter grade.
Now I want to monitor the progress in time using letter grades. So basically I want a line chart where the X axis is the date and the Y axis is the letter grade.
When I insert a line chart and select data in the following format:
DATE/MODULE    01.06.2024    01.07.2024    01.08.2024    01.08.2024
Module 1           E             E             C             C
Module 2           D             D             B             A
Module 3           C             C             A             A

I want to see the progress made in every module for each measurement point (date)
I tried the way I use to create line charts when letters are exchanged by integers, it works fine. But how can I change it to work with letter grades?

In an Excel chart, there must be numbers on the value (Y) axis. There is no way around it.
The only thing that can be done, I think, is to use special formatting so that the numbers look like letters. You can write an event macro that, after typing the letter A..E will convert it into a number in the range 4..0, but visually leave the letter. Thanks to this trick, Excel will "see" the numbers, and the man - letters and the chart can be made.
The macro code must be placed in the sheet module.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, t As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
            Set t = Target(i, j)
            If t Like "[A-E]" Then
                t.NumberFormat = """" & t & """"
                t.Value = Asc("E") - Asc(t)
            ElseIf t.NumberFormat Like """[A-E]""" Then
                t.NumberFormat = "General"
            End If
    Next j, i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


